# Generating random email addresses (more efficient append)

Tags: java

I am taking intro to computer science and our professor gave us some labs to do, one of which is making an email for students.

The rules are:
1. Ask user for first and last name.
2. Use the first letter of the first name, the first 6 letters of the last name, and a 3 digit random number to make an email address. All lower case.
**Example**: If user input Joe Humphry, then the output would be:
**jhumphr167@students.nyu.edu.**

I think I have it figured out, but I am curious if there is a more efficient way to go about it.
My question is:
**Is there a more efficient way to code this, specifically with the appends, so that I won't have to make a new line of code for each append?**

I tried to use:
 `append(num1, num2, num3)`
to no avail.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //asks for first name
    System.out.println("What is your first name?");
    String firstname = scan.next();


    //asks for last name
    System.out.println("What is your last name?");
    String lastname = scan.next();
    if (lastname.length()>6)
        lastname = lastname.substring(0,6);

    //generates random number
    int min = 0;
    int max = 9;
    StringBuilder randoms = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    int num1 = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
    int num2 = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
    int num3 = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
    randoms.append(num1);
    randoms.append(num2);
    randoms.append(num3);

    // combine and print
    System.out.println(firstname.toLowerCase().charAt(0)
                        + lastname.toLowerCase()
                        + randoms
                        + "@students.nyu.edu");

}
```

Comment: there is no such method `append(num1, num2, num3)` in `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your three-digit number at once, instead of generating three separate digits. Remember to format the number, so when it generates value of 0, you will get "jhumphr000" instead of "jhumphr0"

```
Random random = new Random();
int number = random.nextInt(1000);
String randoms = String.format("%03d", number);
```

Comment: This helps the most, but it makes my question obsolete since Stringbuilder is no longer relevant if I go with this method. The only reason I was using it was because I was having a hard time concatenating the different types. Thank you, kind sir.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! You asked if there is a more efficient way of coding this, and didn't specified that you want to use a Builder, so I provided a little more concise way of doing that. Also, I'd be happy if you mark my anwer as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder Class is exactly that: a Builder, so you can use the benefits of the append method, since it returns is the instance self of your class...

Try this:

```
randoms.append(num1).append(num2).append(num3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of these 6 lines,

```
int num1 = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
int num2 = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
int num3 = random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
randoms.append(num1);
randoms.append(num2);
randoms.append(num3);
```

Simply write,

```
 randoms.append((random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min)+""+(random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min)+""+(random.nextInt(max-min+1)+min));
```